# How is it possible to use a single fragment in place of multiple fragments to load same format contents inside of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am facing a situation as of few days now. I intend to create an activity where there is a TabLayout and a ViewPager.

The tabs in TabLayout corresponds with the fragments/slides in the ViewPager.

Now as of now, each fragment contains the same format,i.e., two TextViews, one under the  other, populated with the strings softcoded in string.xml

But this resulted in the creation of too much xml files for the fragments used inside ViewPager.

So I was thinking if it's possible to use only one fragment inside the ViewPager and then programmatically set the strings for those two TextViews in the fragment, that changes each time w.r.t. click on another tab or sliding on the ViewPager area.

This will lessen the no. of fragments to only one, in turn cutting the time to create it and increase the overall performance of the app in which it will be present.

So any insightful help, suggestion, or walkthrough on how to implement this concept - any help on how to do this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do that. If you're using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, just initiate the same fragment with different arguments supplied according to it's position and then in fragment check for those arguments and make changes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for making it known to me that it's possible. But if I may, could you please a demo. For instance, for the sake of clarity, if I want to use one fragment in place of two fragments. I have two TextView elements in each fragment.
How will I initiate the only one fragment with arguments for two fragments that contains two textview elements.
Pardon me for pressing for more details, but as I am new in this field, any help if a bit detailed is great for  me to follow through.

Comment: If you could post your code here, I will be able to help you better.